# Select by next instance of class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to convert a function that selects by id to select the next instance of a given class.

Here is the code.

```
function swap3(oldDivId, newDivId) {
var oldDiv = document.getElementById(oldDivId);
var newDiv = document.getElementById(newDivId);
oldDiv.style.display = "none";
newDiv.style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you have this HTML:

```html
<div id="test"></div>
<img>
<br>
<div></div>
<input>
<div class="abc">Found it</div>
<div class="cdf"></div>
```

### Updated at 2021

The original answer is quite old now. Since the original question have the jQuery tag, the answer keeps valid and usable. But for those coming here with the hope to see an updated JavaScript code with no dependency on jQuery, take a look on how `querySelector` is a awesome nowadays:

```
const next = document.querySelector('#test ~ .abc')
next.textContent = 'Yeah, you found it!'
```

So the secret is to use the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) that matches all iterations of the second element, but with [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) that returns only the first match.

### Original answer

So you select the first `div` by `id`:

```
var some = $("#test");
```

Then you want to find the next `div` with the class `abc`:

```
var next = some.nextAll("div.abc");
```

Suppose you want a variable as the `className`:

```
var x = "abc";
var next = some.nextAll("div." + x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Select by ID in jQuery:

```
$('#class_name')
```

Select by class in jQuery:

```
$('.class_name')
```

Get the next item in jQuery:

```
$('.class_name').next('.class_name')
```

Using this, you can do something like

```
// Something to remember the current element
var currentElement = false;

function getNext(className)
{
    // First time, there will be no current element
    if (!currentElement)
    {
        currentElement = $('.' + className);
        return currentElement;
    }

    // Other times...
    currentElement = $(currentElement).next('.' + className);
    return currentElement;
```

Comment: What if class name has to be a javascript variable?

Comment: `$('#class_name').next()` will give you the next sibling element, not the next instance of a class...

Comment: @PhilipK: You could just use `$('.'+varname)`  But .next() will give you the next sibling in the DOM, this doesn't have to be of the same classname.

Comment: @Sime Edit: Totally misread your comment, I should probably go to bed :) Sorry about that, updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question:

```
function nextItem(className) {
    return $('#ID').closest('.' + className);
}
```

using closest: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: I need className to be a variable I have expanded my code example.